# PHP Gearman too much mysql connections

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, joomla, gearman

I'm using Gearman in a custom Joomla application and using Gearman UI to track active workers and jobs number.

I'm facing an issue with MYSQL load and number of connections, I'm unable to track the issue, But I've few questions that might help me.

1- Does Gearman Workers launch a new database connection for each job or do they share the same connection?

2- If Gearman launches a new connection everytime a job runs how can I change that to make all jobs share same connection?

3- How can I balance the load between more than one server?

4- Is there is something like "Pay-as-you-go" package for MYSQL hosting? if yes, Please mention them.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I dont know how exactly your app is running. Gearman itself only uses persistent queue to write to the queue & read from it after a restart. So Gearman uses only one connection. I believe your jobs will launch a new mysql connection everytime, since its your job, gearman can't help you here. You have to fix it in your worker code. http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php can possibly help here. To 3) thats whats gearman for? Just one Server and multiple clients from everywhere...gearman will handle it..4) - sorry, dont know :(

Comment: @dominik.mank 3) I want to run the workers on more than one server, not one server. Is that possible using Gearman?

Comment: Please take a look at the image http://gearman.org/img/cluster.png from the distributor http://gearman.org. Yes, its possible, but no i cant say how its done for your application, since it depends on how you are using gearman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often an overlooked issue when using any kind of a job queue with workers.  100 workers will open a separate database connection each (they are separate PHP processes).  If MySQL is configured allow 50 connections, workers will start failing. To answer your questions:

1) Each worker runs inside one PHP process each, and that process will open 1 database connection.  Workers do not share database connections.

2) If only one worker is processing jobs, then only one database connection will be opened.  If you have 50 workers running, expect 50 database connections.  Since these are not web requests, persistent connections will not work, sharing will not work.

3) You can balance the load by adding READ slaves, and using a MySQL proxy to distribute the load.

4) I've never seen a pay-as-you-go MySQL hosting solution.  Ask your provider to increase your number of connections.  If they won't, it might be time to run your own server.

Also, the gearman server process itself will only use one database connection to maintain the queue (if you have enabled mysql storage).

Strategies you can use to try and make your worker code play nicely with the database:

1. After each job, terminate the worker and start it up again.  Don't open a new database connection until a new job is received.  Use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to keep your workers running all the time.
2. Close database connections after every query.  if you see a lot of connections open in a 'sleep' state, this will help clean them up and keep database connections low.  Try `$pdo = null;` after each query (if you use PDO).
3. Cache frequently used queries where the result doesn't change, to keep database connections low.
4. Ensure your tables are properly indexed so queries run as fast as possible.
5. Ensure database exceptions are caught in a try/catch block.  Add retry logic (while loop), where the worker will fail gracefully after say, 10 attempts.  Make sure the job is put back on the queue after a failure.

Comment: Thanks @Kris I think this answers all of my questions. I only have one question for now. How can use more than one server to run the Gearman workers? Should I register workers on all servers and copy files to all of them and just used ( addServer ) function, or what exactly?

Comment: Yes that's right, you copy your code to more servers, essentially cloning them, and run the workers.  This is how you scale out as your workload increases.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important thing to look at, before anything else, is the MySQL load. It might be that you have some really heavy queries that are causing this mess. Have you checked the MySQL slow query log? If yes, what did you find? Note that any query that takes more than a second to execute is a slow query.

Comment: Well, I am using persistent storage for workers, that means too much serialized arrays being inserted in the database to manage Jobs queue. I think this is the reason behind this much MYSQL load I am facing. Currently, I am trying to find a different solution like sessions or files storage.